# How to add title to Content page in xamarin forms programmatically?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add title to navigation bar, if i specify Title in xaml page, it is being displayed but i want to add title during my execution of c# code.

I have tried following already:
1. Title = groupName;
2. SetBinding(Page.TitleProperty, groupName);

TIA

**Update:**

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Title = groupName; });
```

worked like a charm. Thanks to Gerald.

Comment: Wrap setting of the title in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {Title = "new title";});`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Never worked on `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`. Got to know now it is like `RunOnUiThread` in native android. Thank you @GeraldVersluis

Comment: Updated it to an answer, please accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the UI, you need to run it on the UI thread. You can do so by wrapping the setting of the title in a call to [BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/), like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    Title = "new title";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In your page constructor give like below

```
    public UserRegistration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "HomePage";

        //Connecting context of this page to the our View Model class
        this.BindingContext = App.Locator.Register;
    }
```

Comment: Title i tried before. It never worked. Thank you @venkata